# Tensor Comparison and Manipulation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

I'm trying to write a custom loss function in Keras. I have `y_pred` and `y_true`. Both are tensors and the values can be `0` or `1`. So, for example, `y_true` is be:

`[0,1,0,1]`

and `y_pred` is:

`[1,1,0,0]`.

I'm trying to compare these two tensors to output the following:

`[-0.7, 2.5, 0.025, -0.1]`

The logic is this:

| y_true | y_pred | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | -0.7 |
| 1 | 1 | 2.5 |
| 0 | 0 | 0.025 |
| 1 | 0 | -0.1 |

I'm not sure the best way of using various tensorflow operations to achieve this. My loss function will take logits, so I'm trying to do this:

```
def roi_loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
  print("Y_TRUE-----")
  print(y_true)
  print("Y_PRED-----")
  print(y_pred)

  softmax = tf.nn.softmax(y_pred)
  print("SOFTMAX-----")
  print(softmax)

  #iterate or manipulate tensors to compare boolean values according to the table
```

EDIT:

This is my current loss function but it's throwing an error: `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable`.

```
def roi_loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):

  y_pred = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
  tf.reshape(y_pred, tf.shape(y_true))

  t_equal = tf.equal(y_true, y_pred)
  t_loss = tf.Variable(tf.zeros_like(y_true, dtype=tf.float32))

  idx = 0
  for x1 in t_equal:
    if x1 == True:
      # Value is either "successful investment" (e.g., 2.5) or "successfully passed" (e.g., 0.025)
      if y_true[idx] == 0:
        t_loss[idx].assign(2.5)
      else:
        t_loss[idx].assign(0.025)
    else:
      # Value is either "bad investment" (e.g., -0.7) or "missed investment" (e.g., -1.4)
      if y_true[idx] == 0:
        t_loss[idx].assign(-0.7)
      else:
        t_loss[idx].assign(-1.4)
    idx += 1
  
  return t_loss
```

Comment: I ended up going with the following but am not sure if it's the best method:


```
for idx, x1 in enumerate(t_equal):
  if x1 == True:
    # Value is either "successful investment" (e.g., 2.5) or "successfully passed" (e.g., 0.025)
    if t1[idx] == 0:
      t_new[idx].assign(2.5)
    else:
      t_new[idx].assign(0.025)
  else:
    # Value is either "bad investment" (e.g., -0.7) or "missed investment" (e.g., -1.4)
    if t1[idx] == 0:
      t_new[idx].assign(-0.7)
    else:
      t_new[idx].assign(-1.4)
```

Comment: Negative values for a loss function is not a good idea. That could stop training if a large negative value added to a large positive value loss sum up to zero.

Comment: Thank you @TouYou. I can edit those parameters so it's not negative. That being said, I'm just trying to get the loss function to work first. Currently it's throwing errors so I can't run the fit function on my model.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use `np.where()` to compare and assign.

Let's take `y_true` and `y_pred` as you said, like this:

```
y_true = tf.constant([0,1,0,1])
y_pred = tf.constant([1,1,0,0])
```

Then, to compare them and assign the desired value, loss function could be like this:

```
def roi_loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):  
   c = tf.zeros(y_pred.shape)
   c = np.where(y_true<y_pred, -0.7, c)
   c = np.where(y_true>y_pred, -0.1, c)
   c = np.where(y_true+y_pred==2, 2.5, c)
   c = np.where(y_true+y_pred==0, 0.025, c)
   return c
```